# Entity attaching to context and unable to remove it

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am creating a context in a method inside my entity to check something but I am not tracking anything with it but when I try to save in the calling code context it throws an exception.

This is the calling code in the main context where I want to save:

```
var espToProcess = db.RootDomainEmailSeriesProgresses;

foreach (var esp in espToProcess)
{
    bool carryOn = esp.MoveNext();
    db.SaveChanges();   //Exception
    if (!carryOn) continue; 

    //--> rest of my code
}
```

This is the methods inside the `RootDomainEmailSeriesProgress` class.

```
public bool MoveNext()
{
    if (this.CompletedTargets == null) this.CompletedTargets = new List<EmailAddress>();

    if (this.CurrentTarget != null)
    {
        this.CompletedTargets.Add(this.CurrentTarget);
        this.CurrentTarget = null;
    }
    this.CurrentProgress = "";

    if (this.RootDomain.ContactFilter != RootDomain.ContactFilterType.None)
    {
        this.Status = EmailSeriesStatus.Aborted;
        return false;
    }

    var allTargets = RootDomainEmailManager.SortDomainsEmailsByDesirability(this.RootDomain.ID);
    var toDo = allTargets.Except(this.CompletedTargets);
    if (toDo.Count() < 1)
    {
        this.Status = EmailSeriesStatus.Completed;
        return false;
    }

    List<string> targetEmailList = allTargets.Select(e => e.Email).ToList();
    List<EmailFilter> emailFilters = this.GetFilters(allTargets);

    if (emailFilters.Any(x => x.Filter == EmailFilterType.Unsubscribe || x.Filter == EmailFilterType.Responded || x.Filter == EmailFilterType.ManualContactOnly))
    {
        this.Status = EmailSeriesStatus.Aborted;
        if (this.RootDomain.ContactFilter == 0) this.RootDomain.ContactFilter = RootDomain.ContactFilterType.HasAssociatedEmailFilter;
        return false;
    }

    this.CurrentTarget = toDo.First();

    return true;

}

private List<EmailFilter> GetFilters(List<EmailAddress> allTargets)
{
    using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
    {
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        var targetEmailList = allTargets.Select(e => e.Email).ToList();
        return db.EmailFilters.AsNoTracking().Where(x => targetEmailList.Contains(x.Email)).ToList();

    }
}
```

It throws out this exception:

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

I can't see why `esp` gets attached to the other context. I only need that context briefly, how do I kill it off so it stops causing me issues?

Answer (score 0):

that because there are difference DbContext instances in foreach loop and GetFilters method

You can retry this code

```
var espToProcess = db.RootDomainEmailSeriesProgresses;

foreach (var esp in espToProcess)
{
    bool carryOn = esp.MoveNext(db);
    db.SaveChanges();   //Exception
    if (!carryOn) continue; 

    //--> rest of my code
}


public bool MoveNext(DbContext db)
{
    if (this.CompletedTargets == null) this.CompletedTargets = new 
List<EmailAddress>();

    if (this.CurrentTarget != null)
    {
        this.CompletedTargets.Add(this.CurrentTarget);
        this.CurrentTarget = null;
    }
    this.CurrentProgress = "";

    if (this.RootDomain.ContactFilter != RootDomain.ContactFilterType.None)
    {
        this.Status = EmailSeriesStatus.Aborted;
        return false;
    }

    var allTargets = 
RootDomainEmailManager.SortDomainsEmailsByDesirability(this.RootDomain.ID);
    var toDo = allTargets.Except(this.CompletedTargets);
    if (toDo.Count() < 1)
    {
        this.Status = EmailSeriesStatus.Completed;
        return false;
    }

    List<string> targetEmailList = allTargets.Select(e => e.Email).ToList();
    List<EmailFilter> emailFilters = this.GetFilters(allTargets, db);

    if (emailFilters.Any(x => x.Filter == EmailFilterType.Unsubscribe || 
x.Filter == EmailFilterType.Responded || x.Filter == 
EmailFilterType.ManualContactOnly))
    {
        this.Status = EmailSeriesStatus.Aborted;
        if (this.RootDomain.ContactFilter == 0) 
this.RootDomain.ContactFilter = 
RootDomain.ContactFilterType.HasAssociatedEmailFilter;
        return false;
    }

    this.CurrentTarget = toDo.First();

    return true;

}

private List<EmailFilter> GetFilters(List<EmailAddress> allTargets, DbContext db)
{
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    var targetEmailList = allTargets.Select(e => e.Email).ToList();
    return db.EmailFilters.AsNoTracking().Where(x => 
targetEmailList.Contains(x.Email)).ToList();
```

}